# Cannot get push menu inline with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap as UI framework, what I'm trying to do is make a push menu on the left. Actually, I almost achieve this result, but there are some bugs on the system. In particular, I'm not able to get the menu inline. See the code for more details:

**HTML**

```
<div id="calendar-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div id="resource-bar" class="sidenav col-sm-2">
                <h4>Resource</h4>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search resource"
                           class="form-control resource-filter"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="clear btn btn-default clean-resource btn-danger" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                </div>

                <div id="popover-content" hidden></div>
            </div>

            <div id="calendar-container" class="col-sm-10">
                <div id="calendar" class="well"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<button type="button" id="show" >Show</button>
<button type="button" id="hide" >Hide</button>
```

Note that the html above is adapted for a fiddle example.

**CSS**

```
.sidenav
{
    background-color: azure;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#calendar-container
{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var resourceContainer = $('#resource-bar');
  var calendarContainer = $('#calendar-container');

    $('#show').click(function()
  {
    resourceContainer.css('width', '250px');
    calendarContainer.css('margin-left', '250px');
  });

  $('#hide').click(function()
  {
    resourceContainer.css('width', '0px');
    calendarContainer.css('margin-left', '0px');
  });
})
```

The result when the menu on the left is closed:

[image]

Seems that both divs are inline, the problem occurs when I press `show` button and the menu appears:

[image]

BUG actually noticed:

1. When the menu is opened I get the divs in two line instead of one row
2. Adding the class `col-sm-2` to `resource-bar` the `overflow-x: hidden;` doesn't working, in fact, seems that the menu is visible when it should be closed.
3. `col-sm-2` does not go in another line when the minimum resolution of the screen doesn't have enough space in width.

Someone could help me to fix this issues? Thanks. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28782/).

Comment: Why are you adjusting the width or margin-left to show or hide divs? Why not just change the CSS visibility attribute between "visible" and "hidden" for these divs?

Comment: @JohnH by setting the width and transitions in css will get a slide effect insteade of a fade effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to another workaround which wouldn't affect bootstrap grid:

- With this setup sidebar would be absolute, since it's out of viewport and you set it to a fixed width (250px), using the grid wouldn't be necessary.
- Visible input will not overflow once sidebar shows.
- Raised `button`s above sidebar.
- Note the HTML structure was tweaked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resourceContainer = $('#resource-bar');
  var calendarContainer = $('#calendar-container');
  $('#show').click(function() {
    resourceContainer.css('width', '250px');
    calendarContainer.css('margin-left', '250px');
  });
  $('#hide').click(function() {
    resourceContainer.css('width', '0px');
    calendarContainer.css('margin-left', '0px');
  });
})
```

```css
div.sidenav {
  background-color: azure;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* added absolute to sidenav since it will have fixed width anyways */
  position: absolute;
}
#calendar-container {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  /* this is just to vertically align with sidebar input */
  padding-top: 36px;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="calendar-container" class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="calendar" class="well"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="resource-bar" class="sidenav">
        <h4>Resource</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search resource" class="form-control resource-filter" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="clear btn btn-default clean-resource btn-danger" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id="popover-content" hidden></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" id="show">Show</button>
<button type="button" id="hide">Hide</button>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You missed problem number 3. By setting the #calendar-container absolute you have removed the main purpose of the boot-strap col-*-* functionality. :)

Comment: @Syden I noticed the same thing suggested by Nasir T, I want ask if is possible adapt the two divs in two rows when the minimum width is reached for the screen. So basically when there isn't enough space bootstrap will create two line but I got a space on the second line, that's the space of the first column. You can see the bug if you enlarge the window to a min width.

Comment: This with the current setup? I have no issues when resizing, included images above.

Comment: @Syden please check this image for a better understanding: http://imgur.com/a/sX32e +1 for your time

Comment: @AgainMe, you sure you are replicating exactly as above? because that is not an issue in the fiddle. I don't see the sidebar taking full height as you specified in your code, neither being `absolute` positioned as in the answer. Also, check the HTML structure, it was tweaked as well.

Comment: @Syden ok I've understood the problem, in particular is `margin-left: 250px;` that has generate the issue. In particular this code add more space between the `resource-bar` and `calendar-container`, so I get a `col-sm-12` that will out of the row, with a consequentially horizontal scroll bar. I don't know if is possible solve this via css, but I though something like js that intercept the button pression and put the class in base of the window resolutiion. What do you think about this? PS: I don't know how to replicate this in jsfiddle, my example code is different from my real code.

Comment: Sorry to insist AgainMe, that's another issue solved above as well. See images on answer and how when sidebar kicks in, input resizes so it never overflows. Here check resizing on this external fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/5mfvj9v2/14/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133379/discussion-between-againme-and-syden).

Answer (score 0):

You're issue lies with the mix of bootstrap and your own JavaScript generated style. It seems you already have knowledge of the Bootstrap Grid layout, but to reinforce, https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/ will tell you that there are 12 columns in a row.

Each column is styled by Bootstrap to a set width with set margins in between. You've have all 12 columns filled up in your row. As you add an additional margin to your already-filled-up calendarContainer column, it will pop out of the row.

Therefore, the easiest way to achieve what you want without affecting any other styles is too make your column smaller and reduce the amount of 'margin-left' you push on the column like so https://jsfiddle.net/Zeenglishking/DTcHh/28837/

```
    <div id="calendar-container" class="col-sm-8">
                <div id="calendar" class="well"></div>
            </div>


  $('#show').click(function()
  {
    resourceContainer.css('width', '250px');
    calendarContainer.css('margin-left', '50px');
  });
```

Also, as you say "seems infact that the menu is even visible also when is closed.", the menu is indeed visible. This is again down to the fact of the bootstrap styling of the grid-layout. If you can figure out what styles are creating this issue (F12), you can override them using "something:!important". https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-override-technique/ . Otherwise, find another way. If you mess around with css positioning elements too much, it's easy to get lost and jumbled with the rest of your code.

EDIT (in regard to comment):

What needs to be used in addition to this is 'col-xs-**' with a smaller size column, allowing for a responsive design and for it to work on the smaller viewports such as the one in JSFiddle. I have updated my fiddle to include

```
col-xs-1
```

and

```
col-xs-4
```

on resource-bar and calendar-container respectively. This will change the size of the column, upon resize of the screen/viewport to ensure it doesn't drop down on extra-small viewports. More info at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Upon using Bootstrap framework you almost acquire yourself to a certain standard. Shortcuts in fixing this can cause problems with other elements. You're probably best to read more into it before chucking random positioning in to fix certain elements on a page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there is another bug, when you reduce the window width you'll get this space: http://imgur.com/a/sX32e

Comment: Ah yes. On my screen it's fine due to my viewport size on jsfiddle being a little larger and therefore classing as col-sm-** and of course, working. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Also might be best to decrease your margin-left js slightly, as the mix of the js and bootstrap sizing still causes the majority of the problem